# What is the homogeneous-elements tag supposed to be used for?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Consider the tag [homogeneous-elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homogeneous-elements).

I ran into this tag today used to describe the rate parameter of an exponential distribution. Given my experience in probability, I'm pretty sure this isn't standard terminology.

Algebra is not my specialty, but it looks like, besides this, this tag is used to describe "homogeneous ideals," "homogeneous polynomials," etc. There is no guidance in the tag wiki which describes what this tag is.

Could someone who has more expertise than I do suggest what to do about this tag, and if we decide to keep it, could someone please put a description in its tag wiki? For now, I'm going to remove this tag from the aforementioned probability question.

Comment: AFAICT the question where the tag was created and the questions added soon after that were from commutative algebra. I have [pinged the tag-creator](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2017/12/19), maybe they join the discussion here on meta and explain the intended usage (or even suggest the tag-wiki).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for pinging me.  I feel connected and stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This tag appears to be intended for questions about homogeneous elements of graded algebraic structures such as graded rings and graded modules.  However, as such, the tag seems wholly redundant with the already-existing tags [graded-rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graded-rings), [graded-modules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graded-modules), and [graded-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graded-algebras).  So I would propose that the tag be removed and that questions with it be retagged with a subset of those tags as appropriate.

Comment: It seems that the result of this discussion is clearly in favor of removal. I have already removed the tag from a few questions - only 5 questions remain. It would probably better if somebody knowledgeable in commutative algebra, graded rings, etc. had a look at the remaining ones - so that appropriate tags can be added at the same time (since the questions are going to be bumped by removal of this tag anyway).

Comment: I've retagged the last 5.

Comment: Thanks for doing that. The tag is now removed also from the system.